# What are the "special" strata of Sym^n(C^2)?

Tags: hilbert-schemes, symmetric-power, cherednik-algebra, primitive-ideal

The affine variety $Sym^n(\mathbb{C}^2)$ has a natural quantization as a spherical rational Cherednik algebra.  Thus, any primitive ideal of the rational Cherednik algebra has an corresponding ideal in $\mathbb{C}[X_1,Y_1..,X_n,Y_n]^{S_n}$.  By a theorem of Ginzburg, the zero-set of this ideal is the closure of the elements where the partition given by looking at which points coincide is a particular fixed one.

**My question:** Which paritions can come up this way?

Comment: I'm slightly confused about the notation---is the ring $C[X_1,...,X_n]^{S_n}$ above supposed to have 2 sets of variables in it, or are you interested in what varieties can appear as supports in the ``base'' also?  Bezrukavnikov-Etingof's recent paper answers the latter question (for each given parameter c of the RCA), but I'm not sure right now how far that goes to answering your question about subvarieties of $Sym^n(C^2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just by coincidence, I was catching up on my arxiv reading and noticed that Losev's [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0239) appears to answer your question.  See part (3) of Theorem 4.3.1 there.  He says it was "known previously".

#### Edit

To be kinder to the reader: the Cherednik algebra is really a family of algebras depending on a parameter $c$; it looks like Losev's result is that at $c=k/m$ for relatively prime integers $k$ and $m$ the varieties we want correspond to partitions of $n$ which are of the form $(m,m,\dots,m,1,1,\dots,1)$ for some number of $m$'s and some number of $1$'s.

#### 2nd Edit

Having looked more carefully at Losev's paper, it seems the idea of the proof is this: in the spirit of [Bezrukavnikov-Etingof](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3639), having fixed a partition $\lambda$ Losev gives (his Theorem 1.3.1) an inductive description of primitive ideals with associated variety corresponding to $\lambda$.  The partition $\lambda$ corresponds to a "parabolic" subgroup $W$ of $S_n$ consisting of those permutations fixing a generic point of the corresponding variety, and the set of primitive ideals corresponding to $\lambda$ is in bijection with the set of primitive ideals of finite codimension in the Cherednik algebra attached to $W$ at the same parameter $c=k/m$.  But $W$ is a product of symmetric groups, so the classification due to [Berest-Etingof-Ginzburg](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208138) of finite dimensional modules for the type $S_n$ Cherednik algebra (they exist exactly when $c$ has denominator $n$) implies the result.

It appears that ideas from Losev's work on finite $W$-algebras also work for symplectic reflection algebras.  It would therefore be nice to understand the finite dimensional modules outside of the symmetric group case a little better.  (And now I'm more motivated to learn about $W$-algebras!)